# Is it possible to use labels within labels in a form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, label

I am building a form which uses labels to define the input values (as many do).

[A sample of this form can be seen here.](http://jsfiddle.net/zrqnT/2/)

My issue, however, is in using things like checkboxes and radio buttons. While I want to define a group of input options, (say something like Gender), using  to then surround my actual inputs with "male" and "female", it seems to cause conflicts, specifically styling wise given it takes the original  css attributes.

What is the best/proper way to use labels within labels where the first label will define an overall area and the subsequent labels are used to merely define the specific input?

### EDIT

The form I demo above is an example of an issue I am facing but for consistency, I plan to use this form styling across several (50+) pages of form collection so while possible, I am trying not to target a **specific** issue, rather solve something across many pages on my site.

Comment: I think what your looking for is a field set http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_legend

Comment: @3rror404 - thanks but that just highlights the overall form. While I suppose I could use fieldset and legend tags, it doesn't have some of the added benefit of the <label> tag, especially with jquery validate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use `fieldset` and `legend` tags instead, e.g.

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>Gender</legend>

   <label for="male"><input type="radio" ... />male</label>
   <label for="female"><input type="radio" ... />female</label>
</fieldset>
```

`fieldset` is a logical container for grouping related inputs and `legend` represents an introductory caption for the fieldset itself. Your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/zrqnT/4/

see also: 
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-fieldset-element
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-legend-element

Comment: This doesn't make since imo.  Not for just one group of radio buttons.

Comment: Also for a couple of related inputs, `fieldset` would be more appropriate than a generic `div` container. I prefer avoid *div-ification* when possible. And legend is a proper tag to introduce them

Comment: You then have to "restyle" the fieldset element to match what he has in the JSFiddle.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan - while I think Fieldset and Legend are valid ways to solve perhaps this particular form, I have other forms on my site that would use this same css stylesheet. On other pages, I have forms already within a fieldset. While I suppose I could simply create separate fieldset and legend classes for the different types, it may cause the same conflict I'm already facing (label within label -> fieldset within fieldset)

Comment: well, of course this answer is meant to be applied to the specific code you posted, but consider that I haven't changed fieldset style (see my my update with your fiddle). I just applied to it the classes you have already specified. The only change in style is for legend element. And imho, I think it's better than using improperly other tags.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan - would you recommend using fieldsets and replacing the DIV and <label> tags altogether then?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the specification:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element

There it says:

> The for attribute may be specified to indicate a form control with
>   which the caption is to be associated. If the attribute is specified,
>   the attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable form-associated
>   element in the same Document as the label element. If the attribute is
>   specified and there is an element in the Document whose ID is equal to
>   the > value of the for attribute, and the first such element is a
>   labelable form-associated > element, then that element is the label
>   element's labeled control.
>
> If the for attribute is not specified, but the label element has a
>   labelable form-associated element descendant, then the first such
>   descendant in tree order is the label element's labeled control.

So, you must provide a for attribute. But this can just be the case if you have a form control with the same id. It's not the case here.
Otherwise you can surround your code with a label, but then your elements must be labelable.

Labelable Elements are:

> Labelable elements
>   Denotes elements that can be associated with label
>   elements.
>
> button input (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state) keygen
>   meter output progress select textarea

So no chance for a label to have this specific behavior in your case

Use fieldset and legend instead

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Gender: <em>*</em></legend>
    <label for="male"><input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="m" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true" />male</label>
    <label for="female"><input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="f" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true" />female</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this CSS

```
#formWrapper label[for=male], #formWrapper label[for=female] { color: red; }
```

This will allow you to change just those labels via straight CSS.  The other option is to just use containing divs.

```
<div class="form-item">
    <label>Gender</label>
    <div class="radios">
         <label for="male">Male</label><input type="radio" for="male"/>
         <label for="female">Female</label><input type="radio" for="female"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the idea but rather not use specific css in this case, especially since there are 8 pages in this form and on some pages, over 30 radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

What Fabrizio said might work, but personally I would just use a heading. You don't necessarily have to use form elements for forms. Plus using a normal heading element would give you much greater flexibility as far as styling goes.

```
<div class="stage clear">
    <h3>Gender: <em>*</em></h3>
    <label for="male"><input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="m" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true" />male</label>
     <label for="female"><input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="f" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true" />female</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I also wouldn't put the input inside of the label, but that's just me. :)

Comment: why not? If the user clicks the text when input is encompassed it selects the element, otherwise they must click the button directly. It is really the only reason to use a label in the first place in my opinion.

Comment: Typically using the "name" attribute on both does the trick... though radio buttons might be different. I can't remember off the top of my head actually.

Comment: @ScottStubblefield It's not the `name` attribute, that is addressed by the labels `for` attribute, but the controls `id` attribute. To avoid having unique descriptors for your labels just surround the form control with the label tag. voilá. See the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element